# UI gets stuck while loading lot of data from realm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I am trying to show 10,000 contacts on listview in xamarin forms using realm. But whenever user traverse to contact listing screen 
it gets freezed and loads after a while.

Moreover , i have provided an option to search from list as well and that too gets stuck as search if performing on UI thread.

Following is the code to load data from realm

```
public override async Task Initialize(Object data )
    {

             private Realm _realmInstance = getRealm();
            if (contactList != null)
            {
                contactList.Clear();
            }


            contactList = _realmInstance.All<Contact>().OrderByDescending(d => d.contactId).ToList(); 
            // here the binding happens with realm data
            contacts = new ObservableCollectionFast<Contact>(contactList);
    }

 public ObservableCollectionFast<Contact> contacts
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {
                items = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("contacts");
            }


        }
```

as it was taking time in loading i thought to fetch realm data in background and bind it on UI thread  as follows 
but that is throwing error

> realm accessed from incorrect thread

```
  await Task.Run(() => {

                contactList = _realmInstance.All<Contact>().OrderByDescending(d => d.contactId).ToList();

            });

            if (contactList.Count() > 0)
            {
                ContactListView = true;
                AddContactMsg = false;
            }
            else
            {
                AddContactMsg = true;
            }


            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                contacts = new ObservableCollectionFast<Contact>(contactList);

            });
```

i wanted to try limiting the results by using `TAKE` function of `LINQ` but unfortunately its not supported by realm yet. not sure how i can smoothly load records from realm to listview.

**EDIT**

as per the SushiHangover i have  changed things from `IList` to `IQueryable`

```
public IQueryable<Contact> contacts
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {
                items = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("contacts");
            }
        }


public override async Task Initialize(Object data )
    {

        _realmInstance = getRealm();
        contacts = dbContactList= _realmInstance.All<Contact>();


    }
```

so far search is working pretty smoothly but `IQueryable` change leads to another issue. on repeatedly performing following steps results in app crash

1. tap on list item
2. detail page gets open then press back
3. scroll down to few records
4. perform step 1 and repeat

this results into stackoverflow error

> 04-19 06:05:13.980 F/art     ( 3943): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   Pending exception java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown by 'void
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.CellAdapter.n_onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView,
>   android.view.View, int, long):-2' 04-19 06:05:13.980 F/art     (
>   3943): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack
>   size 8MB

[Link to entire log file](https://files.fm/u/rega9vb8)

code to fire item click command is

```
public ICommand OnContactSelectCommand => new Command<Contact>(OnContactSelect);
```

following code will open ups a detail page

```
private  async void OnContactSelect(Contact contact)
        {
            if (contact != null)
            {
               await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<ContactDetailViewModel>(contact.mContactId);
            }

        }
```

**Note:**

when i replace `IQueryable` with `List` i do not face any error

somehow my issue is related to [realm github thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1575) where user is getting exception on `listView.SelectedItem = null` while using `IQueryable`

here is my code of list view item tap

```
 private static void ListViewOnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listView = sender as ListView;

            if (listView != null && listView.IsEnabled && !listView.IsRefreshing)
            {
                // have commented this line because it was crashing the app
                //listView.SelectedItem = null;


                var command = GetItemTappedCommand(listView);
                if (command != null && command.CanExecute(e.Item))
                {
                    command.Execute(e.Item);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: You do not want to take your RealmQuery to a list (`.ToList`), that is iterating over the entire table and instancing 10,000 C# objects. Plus ensure that your Forms' ListView is using `RecycleElement` as its caching strategy as the default is to retain the elements....

Comment: are you suggesting to use `IOrderedQueryable<Contact> contacts` and then using `contacts = _realmInstance.All<Contact>().OrderByDescending(d => d.contactId);` ?

Comment: @SushiHangover can you please see my edits

Comment: I end up using `toList` as using `IOrderQueryable<Contact>` is throwing error while tapping on list item